# Follow notifications not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, email, following

I have created a SP2013 (Oct CU) farm using `SPAutoInstaller` which meets the client requirement of a single Web App. MySites is a site collection hosted on this web app with the usual `/personal/` managed paths. Not seeing any obvious problems that would upset users except:

- A doc or site follow generates a confirmation and even updates MySites News Feeds but **NO EMAIL is even sent out to the user**
- server email address is correct and Alert me on doc libs works no problem
- user profile email option and privacy check boxes all checked for every user via my custom PS script
- Service apps and services all started and enabled

I am seeing some odd uls errors including:

> Dist cache Unexpected error occurred in method 'GetObject' , usage 'Distributed Logon Token Cache' - Exception 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode

This may, or may not be related - I need to prioritise on the issue above.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have the same issue

Comment: Hi, I don't know but will find out. I support this client remotely and I have patched their farm to SP1. I will find out if they have noticed any improvements